# How can I sort the lines in large text file by custom function in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting

I have text files with the structure that the first line contains tab seprated keys, and all subsequent lines contain tab separated values for those keys. So each line can be turned into a map of key value pairs using the first line.

I want to sort the lines of such files by some key in the map and save them sorted.

I read the file like this:

```
def parseTxtSimple(path: String):Array[String]=
{
   Source.fromFile(path).getLines().toArray
}
```

Then I sort it using a compfunc:

```
val lines=parseTxtSimple(key+"/"+name)

// identify record keys from first line ( used by compfunc )
// strip is my own function that removes all \r and \n characters

val header=strip(lines.head).split("\t")

// sort lines

val lines_sorted:Array[String]=lines.tail.sortWith((leftE,rightE) => compfunc(leftE,rightE)).toArray
```

This is the compfunc:

```
def compfunc(leftE:String,rightE:String):Boolean =
{
   val leftEr=(header zip strip(leftE).split("\t")).toMap
   val rightEr=(header zip strip(rightE).split("\t")).toMap
   var ratingLeftE:Float=0.0.toFloat
   var ratingRightE:Float=0.0.toFloat
   if(leftEr.contains("rating")) ratingLeftE=myToFloat(leftEr("rating"))
   if(rightEr.contains("rating")) ratingRightE=myToFloat(rightEr("rating"))
   ratingLeftE > ratingRightE
}
```

My problem is that sorting is slow and for even 20 MB text files the program runs out of memory.

If I read in the text file instead of an array of strings as an array of arrays of values ( by splitting every line by "\t" ) and use these preprocessed arrays instead of splitting them by "\t" in compfunc, the situation is not better.

The whole program is found here:

https://github.com/fideplayerslist/fideplayerslist/blob/master/players.scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def printOutput(header : Array[String], sorted : Array[String]) {
      println(header.mkString("\t"))
      sorted.foreach { x => println(x) }

  }
  def parseAndSortFile(lines: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val header = lines.head.split("\t")
    val ratingColumn = header.indexOf("ratings")
    if (ratingColumn == -1) {
      println("could not find ratings column");
    } else {
      val values = lines.tail.map { x => x.split("\t") }
      val sorted = (values.sortBy[Float] { x => x(ratingColumn).toFloat }).map(x => x.mkString("\t"))
      printOutput(header, sorted) // Replace this with whatever you want to do with the sorted data.
    }

  }

  import scala.io._
  val now = new Date().getTime
  parseAndSortFile(Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.toArray)
  println(new Date().getTime-now)
```

This should reduce the usage of memory and speed-up your sorting. However, since you are sorting in-memory, there will always be a cap to maximum size. Make sure your heap is large enough.

I have used a 2 gb heap size.

32 mb file took 16 seconds

65 mb file took 34 seconds

98 mb file took 61 seconds

**Note:** comment out the call to printOutput when you do the timing.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. The sorting has become lightning fast. Unfortunately this solution runs out of memory earlier ( I guess because you store the splitted strings - as I did in my first attempt - to make looking up the key faster ). At least now I can do the sorting for the vast majoriy of files with your quick method, and do the few big ones with my slow, less memor intensive method. Still there two files with which I run out of memory no matter what method I use.

Comment: I tried to vote up your answer, but my reputation is not enough to make my vote count. I think I miss 2 reputation points for my vote to count. I could accept your answer though and I did so.

Answer (score 0):

It occured to me that I can sort an arbitrarily large file, as long as all the sorting keys that occur in the file fit into memory and can be sorted as a string array.

Here how it goes ( very impractical, but works for any file size ):

Parse the text file line by line, establish the sorting key in the current line, open a file named after this sorting key for appending and append this line, at the same time add the key to the array of keys ( or a map to avoid adding multiple times ).

When you finished you have as many files as the occuring values of the sorting key.

Now, sort the array of sorting keys and for every sorting key in order append the file belonging to this key to the sorted file. In the end you get the large file sorted.

As a matter of fact in my case there are only a few thousand possible values of the sorting key, so this method would surely work, just the many necessary file operations would make it slow.